# pytorch sets grad attribute to none if I use simple minus instead of -=

Tags: python, pytorch, in-place, autodiff

This is a simple code to show the problem

```py
import torch
X = torch.arange(-3, 3, step=0.1)
Y = X * 3
Y += 0.1 * torch.randn(Y.shape)

def my_train_model(iter):
    w = torch.tensor(-15.0, requires_grad=True)
    lr = 0.1
    for epoch in range(iter):
        print(w.grad)
        yhat = w * X
        loss = torch.mean((yhat - Y) ** 2)
        loss.backward()

        with torch.no_grad():
            print(w.grad)
            w = w - lr * w.grad # gradient exists if w-= lr*w.grad
            print(w.grad)
            w.grad.zero_()
        print(loss)

my_train_model(4)
```

This sets the w.grad to `none` after performing the `w = w - lr * w.grad`, but the problem will be solved if I use `w -= lr * w.grad` instead of the above expression!

What is the problem with the first expression which sets `w.grad` to `none`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `torch.no_grad()` guarantees that no gradient is computed, which means any component wrapped in there is created with `requires_grad=False`, as you can see in [this example](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#locally-disabling-gradient-computation).

The in-place operation only changes the value of the tensor, from [this answer from forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-in-place-operation/16244):

> An in-place operation is an operation that changes directly the content of a given Tensor without making a copy.

Therefore, with the problem that you proposed, `w = w - lr * w.grad` will replace `w` by the copy of itself without gradient, and `w -= lr * w.grad` only change the content of tensor which is still keep the gradient of itself from the operation outside of `torch.no_grad()`.